# Undefined property of a typed Array (Typescript)?

Tags: typescript

I've been struggling with a simple problem (but it's already givin' me a headache).
I have the code below:

```
interface IFoo{
   ReturnFirstBarObject1(): string;
   FillBarArray(array: Array<Bar>): void;
}

class Bar {
  object1: string;
  object2: string;
}

class Foo implements IFoo{
  array: Array<Bar>;

  constructor(){
    this.array = new Array<Bar>();
  }

  public ReturnFirstBarObject1(): string {
     return this.array[0].object1;
  }

  public FillBarArray(array: Array<Bar>): void {
     this.array = array;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  var foo = new Foo();

  $.get('url/getBars?FooID=1')
   .done(function(data: any){
       foo.FillBarArray(data);
   });

  var object1 = foo.ReturnFirstBarObject1();
});
```

I don't know why but object1 returns for me as 'undefined' and when I highlight 'this.array[0]' it returns a JSon like this

```
"{'object1' : 'someString', 'object2' : 'someString'}"
```

I want to access object1 but it returns undefined and I can't do a workaround on the Json because typescript recognize the array object as a Bar.

Anyone knows why this is happening and what can I do to access Bar property properly ?

Comment: `string object1 = ...` is not valid syntax. Perhaps you meant `let object1:string = ...` ? Also, you instantiate `Foo` but never assign any values to `array` so `array[0]` would not exist.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, if you have a class Bar and you want to access its property you may directly use from the object of Bar with an string indexer like objOfBar['object1'] or objOfBar.object1

Comment: @Aaron sorry, i'm already editing that. The values are provided by a return. The real problem is the value that return 'undefined'

Comment: I have an ajax that returns the values and insert them in the array. Everything runs smooth, with the exception of this that I can't access.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan I'm sorry if I expressed myself badly. My object is filled with an ajax return with an Array of Bars. The problem is that I don't know why the browser in runtime can't recognize the properties inside Bar.

Comment: Maybe the result is a json string not a json object. Did you try `$.getJSON`? also try a console.log of `data` before calling `FillBarArray`.

Comment: @fips I'll try that. I return with the answer in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result here is a json string not a json object. Try `$.getJSON`.

Also @Madhu Ranjan's answer about jquery's callback possibly returning after the call to `ReturnFirstBarObject1` is another thing to consider that could cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to get the first element before you have filled the `array`,

below code executes before your ajax calls fills the array, hence you are getting undefined error.

```
var object1 = foo.ReturnFirstBarObject1();
```

If you move this code inside ajax call it should work,

```
$.get('url/getBars?FooID=1')
  .done(function(data: Array<Bar>){
     foo.FillBarArray(data);
     var object1 = foo.ReturnFirstBarObject1();
});
```

Comment: @fips You got that, i'm feeling realy stupid now. My return in ajax was data: any, and it was binding the whole json to the array. I'll edit my question and you answer it and I'll give you a +1. thanks.

Comment: @MadhuRanjan thanks for the help. My method where returning an Json and the binding didn't occur like I was thinking. Thanks guys, you're all awesome.